# Position of button or text changes depending on content inside is present or not

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please take a look at the following code

```js
var clicked = false;

function myfunction() {
  if (!clicked) {
    clicked = true;
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("h");
    document.getElementById("button-id").appendChild(textnode);
  } else {
    clicked = false;
    var elem = document.getElementById("button-id");
    elem.removeChild(elem.childNodes[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
.button-class {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div><button class="button-class" id="button-id" onclick="myfunction();"></button> Do this</div>
```

Whenever I fill the button with some content, the position of text alongside it  changes (in Chrome). While on Firefox, the position of button changes. Why are these these changes in position happening?

The link for codepen for the same code is - https://codepen.io/piyush1104/pen/OJyQmZz

If it is a duplicate of some other question, please tell me. I have made many google searches and has been unable to find anything related to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typical baseline issue (not always easy to find given how some questions are formulated).

A simplified explanation: With no text, the line height is `0`, so it aligns to that point. When there is text, the line height shifts, so the button moves to get the bottom of the text aligned with the rest of the text.

You can easily fix it with `vertical-align: middle;`:

```js
var clicked = false;

function myfunction() {
  if (!clicked) {
    clicked = true;
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("h");
    document.getElementById("button-id").appendChild(textnode);
  } else {
    clicked = false;
    var elem = document.getElementById("button-id");
    elem.removeChild(elem.childNodes[0]);
  }
}
```

```css
.button-class {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div><button class="button-class" id="button-id" onclick="myfunction();"></button> Do this</div>
```

Comment: I know some of the ways to solve it, but I wanted to know why it happens?

Comment: Updated my answer to give some context. I hope this helps!

Comment: This explanation works for Firefox but I think I can formulate the similar reasoning for Chrome's behavior. Still weird, how browsers are handling this differently.

Comment: While one browser is attempting to keep the whole line in the same spot (only the line below would reflow), the other is letting the button govern the line-height (the concerned line and the ones below move up). There's probably a (lack of) spec document that can explain this difference.

Comment: I searched a lot, but your answer did it simply and perfectly, many thanks.